# Django datetime comparison not working as expected in save

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I have a custom save routine in one of my models that compares `datetime` fields and then is supposed to modify a field on another model and save it based on the results. However, the comparison is not working as I would expect it to. Namely, my `<=` comparison is returning `True` regardless of the actual comparison.

```
models.py

class Session(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    # etc...

class Case(models.Model):
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cases')
    case_type = models.ForeignKey(CaseType)
    # etc...

class Person(models.Model):
    earliest_case = models.ForeignKey('Case', null=True, blank=True, related_name='person_to_earliest_case+')
    latest_case = models.ForeignKey('Case', null=True, blank=True, related_name='person_to_latest_case+')
    # etc...


class Litigant(models.Model):

    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='person_to_case')
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='case_to_person')
    # etc...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         try:
             person = Person.objects.get(id=self.person_id)
             earliest_case = person.earliest_case
             latest_case = person.latest_case
             if self.case.session.date <= earliest_case.session.date:
                  person.earliest_case = self.case
                  person.save()
             elif self.case.session.date >= latest_case.session.date:
                  person.earliest_case = self.case
                  person.save()
         except:
             pass
         super(Litigant, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see, when I save a new `Litigant`, what I *want* it to do is call up the existing `Person` instance, compare that instance's entries for `earliest_case` and `latest_case` with the new `Case` instance tied to `Litigant` and then reassign the fields if necessary.

What is happen instead is that the new `case` is being added to `person.earliest_case` *regardless* of whether it is earlier or later than the existing date there, and I'm not really sure why.

For reference, the dates stored in the `Session` date field are all `Year-Date-Month`.

Frustratingly, if I call up two instances of `case.session.date` in the shell, they compare just fine.

If it matters, the `case` fk is getting added by my view like so:

```
views.py

def add_litigant(request, pk):
     case_instance = get_object_or_404(models.Case, pk=pk)
     if request.method == "POST":
         form = forms.LitigantForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             new_litigant = form.save(commit=False)
             new_litigant.case = case_instance
             new_litigant.save()
     # etc...

# def edit_litigant works the same way
```

I would appreciate any guidance or pointers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a start, you **must** remove that `except: pass`. You should never, ever do that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will move it around so that way it does `try: earliest_case = person.earliest_case` and then does the logic, with the `except:` being simply assigning the case. That way if the person doesn't have an existing earliest (or latest) case it will just dump it in there. Thanks for pointing that out!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is happen instead is that the new case is being added to person.earliest_case regardless of whether it is earlier or later than the existing date there, and I'm not really sure why.

That's why:

```
if self.case.session.date <= earliest_case.session.date:
    person.earliest_case = self.case  # <- assigned to earliest_case
    person.save()
elif self.case.session.date >= latest_case.session.date:
    person.earliest_case = self.case   # <- assigned to earliest_case. COPYPASTA!
    person.save()
```